# Angular 2 routing child issue

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I'm trying to add child routes on my home component but when i click on router link i got this exception

```
vendor.bundle.js:530 Angular is running in the development mode. Call    enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
main.bundle.js:63 NgForm
error_handler.js:54 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot   match any routes. URL Segment: 'home/teste'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'home/teste'
   at ApplyRedirects.noMatchError   (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:82905:16) [angular]
    at CatchSubscriber.selector (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:82874:29) [angular]
    at CatchSubscriber.error (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:66570:31) [angular]
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:6330:26) [angular]
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:6304:18) [angular]
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:6330:26) [angular]
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:6304:18) [angular]
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:6330:26) [angular]
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:6304:18) [angular]
    at LastSubscriber.Subscriber._error (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:6330:26) [angular]
    at LastSubscriber.Subscriber.error (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:6304:18) [angular]
    at MergeAllSubscriber.OuterSubscriber.notifyError (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:47060:26) [angular]
    at InnerSubscriber._error (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:86738:21) [angular]
    at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.error (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:6304:18) [angular]
 ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:54
next @ application_ref.js:348
schedulerFn @ async.js:93
SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:234
SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:183
Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
Subject.next @ Subject.js:55
EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:79
NgZone.triggerError @ ng_zone.js:333
onHandleError @ ng_zone.js:294
webpackJsonp.619.ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:334
webpackJsonp.619.Zone.runGuarded @ zone.js:142
_loop_1 @ zone.js:540
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:549
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:420
error_handler.js:59 ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:59
next @ application_ref.js:348
schedulerFn @ async.js:93
SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:234
SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:183
Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
Subject.next @ Subject.js:55
EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:79
NgZone.triggerError @ ng_zone.js:333
onHandleError @ ng_zone.js:294
webpackJsonp.619.ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:334
webpackJsonp.619.Zone.runGuarded @ zone.js:142
_loop_1 @ zone.js:540
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:549
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:420
error_handler.js:60 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match      any routes. URL Segment: 'home/teste'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'home/teste'
at ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (apply_redirects.js:149) [angular]
at CatchSubscriber.selector (apply_redirects.js:118) [angular]
at CatchSubscriber.error (catch.js:104) [angular]
at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:128) [angular]
at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:102) [angular]
at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:128) [angular]
at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:102) [angular]
at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:128) [angular]
at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:102) [angular]
at LastSubscriber.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:128) [angular]
at LastSubscriber.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:102) [angular]
at MergeAllSubscriber.OuterSubscriber.notifyError (OuterSubscriber.js:22) [angular]
at InnerSubscriber._error (InnerSubscriber.js:26) [angular]
at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:102) [angular]
at resolvePromise (zone.js:643) [angular]
at resolvePromise (zone.js:619) [angular]
at polyfills.bundle.js:2957:17 [angular]
at Object.onInvokeTask (ng_zone.js:264) [angular]
at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.619.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:362) [angular]
at Zone.webpackJsonp.619.Zone.runTask (zone.js:166) [<root> => angular]
at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:529) [<root>]
at HTMLAnchorElement.ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:420) [<root>]
ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:60
next @ application_ref.js:348
schedulerFn @ async.js:93
SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:234
SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:183
Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
Subject.next @ Subject.js:55
EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:79
NgZone.triggerError @ ng_zone.js:333 
onHandleError @ ng_zone.js:294
webpackJsonp.619.ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:334 
webpackJsonp.619.Zone.runGuarded @ zone.js:142
_loop_1 @ zone.js:540
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:549
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:420
zone.js:516 Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot match any routes. URL          Segment: 'home/teste' ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value:       ZoneAwareError {__zone_symbol__error: Error: Cannot match any routes. URL     Segment: 'home/teste'
   at ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (http:/…, __zone_symbol__stack:       "Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'home…   ocalhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:6304:18) [angular]",    __zone_symbol__message: "Cannot match any routes. URL Segment:    'home/teste'"} Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'home/teste'
    at ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:82905:16) [angular]
    at CatchSubscriber.selector (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:82874:29) [angular]
    at CatchSubscriber.error (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:66570:31) [angular]
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:6330:26) [angular]
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:6304:18) [angular]
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:6330:26) [angular]
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:6304:18) [angular]
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error  (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:6330:26) [angular]
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:6304:18) [angular]
    at LastSubscriber.Subscriber._error (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:6330:26) [angular]
    at LastSubscriber.Subscriber.error (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:6304:18) [angular]
    at MergeAllSubscriber.OuterSubscriber.notifyError (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:47060:26) [angular]
    at InnerSubscriber._error (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:86738:21) [angular]
    at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.error (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:6304:18) [angular]
 consoleError @ zone.js:516
_loop_1 @ zone.js:545
 drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:549
 ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:420
 zone.js:518 ZoneAwareError {__zone_symbol__error: Error: Uncaught (in   promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'home/teste'
Error: Canno…, rejection: ZoneAwareError, promise: ZoneAwarePromise,   zone: Zone, task: ZoneTask…}
consoleError @ zone.js:518
_loop_1 @ zone.js:545
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:549
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:420
```

my home module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HOME_ROUTING } from './home.routing';
import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';
import { MenuComponent } from '../menu/menu.component';
import { TesteComponent } from '../teste/teste.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
   CommonModule,
   HOME_ROUTING
  ],
  declarations: [
    HomeComponent,
    MenuComponent,
    TesteComponent,
  ],
  providers: [] 
})
export class HomeModule {}
```

My home routing

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { TesteComponent } from '../teste/teste.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';

const HOME_ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home',
    children: [
      { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
      { path: 'teste', component: TesteComponent, outlet:'homeRouterOutlet' },
   ]
 }
];

export const HOME_ROUTING: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(HOME_ROUTES);
```

my router link

```
<li><a [routerLink]="['teste']">Crear</a>
```

my app.routing

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

const ROUTES : Routes = [
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },

  // otherwise redirect to home
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full' }
];

export const ROUTING = RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES);
```

This exception happens when I click on my link i don't know why. I already search some solutions for it, but without success, i hope that someone could help me with this.

Comment: what is your home route then?

Comment: put your app-routing configs

Comment: Bougarfaoui El Houcine i added the app-routing

Comment: where do you import your ROUTING? I couldn't see it in App module

Comment: I add it on app.module

Comment: code formatting; grammar